# Rand() Conversion Warning

Tags: c, random, type-conversion, c99

I have :

```
r = ((float)(rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX)) *  BOUND);
```

this also gives the same warning:

```
r = ((rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX)) *  BOUND);
```

And the warning:

```
 conversion to ‘float’ from ‘int’ may alter its value
```

Any possible fixes?

Comment: Use `double`.  `float` is too imprecise - may lose valuable bits from `int`.  Why are you casting to `float` instead of `double` anyways?  Or maybe use `1.0*rand()/RAND_MAX *  BOUND;`

Comment: because at first it was double, but trying to fix it .. did some stupid stuff

Comment: I tried compiling this. I defined BOUND as 100. Did not get any warnings. This was compiling in Xcode 7.1 on OSX. What environment are you compiling in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `RAND_MAX` and the return value of `rand()` itself are of type `int`.

A 32bit `int` can have a maximum value (`INT_MAX`) of up to ten digits.

A `float` -- commonly implemented as 32 bit FP -- has about 6 digits of precision.

This means that there is not enough precision to distinguish e.g. 2,147,483,64**7** from 2,147,483,64**6**. This is why the compiler generates that warning: Your conversion is not safe for all cases.

The quick fix is to use `double`, which is commonly implemented as 64 bit FP, having about 15 digits of precision. That's enough to hold a 32bit `int` (but not enough for a 64bit one).

All in all, `rand()` is a terrible function, and the standard allows it to be quite bad on the "randomness" as well. If you need *good* random numbers, you shouldn't rely on the standard library, but use a dedicated third-party solution (which usually includes functions that return floating point right away).

Answer (score 0):

You get this warning because `float` variables do not have enough precision to hold any possible value an `int` can take. That means the cast can produce a wrong result if the integer you're casting from is too large. For example, an integer like `1 000 000 451` would be cast to `1.000000E9`, making it wrong by `451`. Depending on the value of your `RAND_MAX` this may or may not actually be a problem in your specific case.

It would be safer to use `double` instead, where you should not have this issue.